# background is not showing up on android studio button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I have set it up to where my button's style is borderless and I'm using a drawable for the button background `android:background="@drawable/circle"`

This is the code for the `@drawable/circle` file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#263238"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and that color (#26338) does not appear on the button instead the button looks like this

[what it looks like in design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au1gG.png)

In case you're wondering heres the XML code for the button

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/clearBTN"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                android:fontFamily="@font/oswald_medium"
                android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
```

When in reality it should be more like this color

[this is the color I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4f6f.png)

Some more additional info is that my button is in a TableRow inside of a tableLayout. Also when I try applying a backgroundTint it also does not work. Am using the latest version of android studio and I'm pretty sure everything else is up to date.

---

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is Button bug.

change `Button`
to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`

Comment: what do I replace with that.

Comment: @iTwisten I eidt my answer

Answer (score 0):

use bellow xml for create button background.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#263238"/>
     
</shape>
```

this code for use drawable with button.@drawable/circle is your background drawable name.

```
<Button
         android:id="@+id/clearBTN"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="@drawable/circle"
         android:fontFamily="@font/oswald_medium"
         android:text="@string/clear"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Buttons.

use AppCompatButton instead using Button.

package : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton